# Storing the data to MongoDB collection to specific name

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I create a script which receives the data from Binance API at sends it to MongoDB. 
The scripts starts every hour with Node-Schedule package and as well it receive three different data's depending on their symbol (BTCUSDT, ETHUSDT, ATOMBTC). I also create a script which is automatically stores the receiving data to MongoDB collection.

Goal: I would like to store the specific data to specific collection. My though was to made a something like `if statement` and have the symbol name same as collection name. For example

```
if symbol name = collection name => save to collection
```

Is this way can help me out? I will have three symbols and three collections. Both of them will have same names.

**Full Code**

```
var today = new Date();
 var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
 var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
 var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

 var symbols = ["BTCUSDT", "ETHUSDT", "ATOMBTC"];
 let cnt = 0;

 const callIt = () => {
     fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbols[cnt]}&interval=1h&limit=1`)
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(data => {
             const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
                 return {
                     Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
                     High: parseFloat(d[2]),
                     Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
                     Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
                     Volume: parseFloat(d[5])
                 }
             });
             console.log(btcusdtdata);
             saveToBTCUSDT(btcusdtdata);
             cnt++;
             if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 3000)
         })
         .catch((err) => {
             console.log(err);

         })

 };
 const j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 * * * *', callIt)


     const saveToBTCUSDT = function(BTCdata) {

         const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

         MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
             if (err) throw err;
             const dbo = db.db('CryptoCurrencies');
             const myobj = { Name: 'BTCUSDT', Array: BTCdata, Date: dateTime };
             dbo.collection('BTCUSDT').insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
                 if (error) throw error;
                 console.log('1 document inserted');
                 db.close();
             });
         });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the current index (count) as a parameter and then address the desired collection with the index.

```
    ...
    saveToBTCUSDT(btcusdtdata, cnt);
    ...

    const saveToBTCUSDT = function(BTCdata, index) {

     const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

     MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
         if (err) throw err;
         const dbo = db.db('CryptoCurrencies');
         const myobj = { Name: symbols[index], Array: BTCdata, Date: dateTime };
         dbo.collection( symbols[index] ).insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
             if (error) throw error;
             console.log('1 document inserted');
             db.close();
         });
     });
   };
```